# OpenCart: Flat Option Cost + Per Item Cost for Products

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, opencart, shopping-cart

In Opencart, I have a product which you select colors of.

Basically the pricing should be: Each additional printing color costs a flat rate of $50 + $0.25 for each.

*So if a person were ordering 1000 items, with 2 colors, the cost would need to be BASECOST + $100($50x2) + $250(1000x$.25)*

Right now I'm only able to set up the cost for each product.  Since people are going to be both ordering large and huge quantities, there's no easy way to build it into the each price.

I could have sworn I saw a free extension awhile ago that allowed you to set both a flat price for an option, and a price for each on the quantity.  Trying searching everything I could think of, but the only thing that I could find is for shipping (we already have a pretty complex setup for the shipping, so can't mess with that).

Has anyone came across a solution, or simple extension for this problem.  Seems like a simple thing, but still can't find a solution for the life of me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can see to do this would be to have fixed costs for certain price breaks which can be done through the `Discount` tab of each product, and can even be set based on customer group if you have wholesale as well as regular customers or other customer groups

Comment: I don't think that's really feasible.  There are already around a lot of different price ranges for each product (for 100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000... etc..), all having different prices per item.

Just want to have a flat cost to the overall price added if an option is selected.  (in addition to the existing per item cost).

Comment: Or perhaps just anything that will let me had a flat cost.  Not necessarily the two, but just adding say $50, $100, or $150 as an option.